# Looking for Projects having extensive usage of (mostly used) design patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to get my hands dirty with some projects (in C++) which have used design patterns extensively.

I have already read design pattern documentation (as well as code) from net and other books (gang of four and Head first), but i am looking for a place where i can get already implemented projects (using design patterns), get my hands dirty with them, understand them, enhance them etc.

Could anybody point me to a place(s) from where I can get design experience in the best possible way? (Please note: Language C++, Complexity of the project can be intermediate to difficult)

Comment: Give the MySQL source code a read. You'll learn some relational database stuff whilst your at it, as well.

Comment: Any well-designed medium-to-large scale project is going to have design patterns. However, no project should use design patterns "extensively". If you have a large number of classical patterns in your project, chances are that either your system was contrived to allow for patterns or you are forcing patterns into your system where they aren't helping. You probably shouldn't be focusing on the use of patterns, but instead on the concepts of good design principles, and in the case of C++, good object-oriented design principles. That includes, but not limited to, the appropriate use of patterns.

Comment: Probably, I should have used "efficient usage of design patterns" instead of "extensive usage".

Comment: @Thomas Owens: if you happen to find only *good object-oriented design principles* in C++ then chances are that either your system was contrived to allow for this OO principles or you are enforcing OO principles into your system where they aren't helping... C++ is multi-paradigm, there is **much** more than OO.

Comment: @Matthiew C++ is primarily object-oriented, although it does support procedural as well. Most of the C++ that I've seen leverages the object-oriented capabilities and should therefore follow good object-oriented design principles.

Answer (score 1):

[ACE](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) is a good example - uses many concurrency and communications patterns.  There's a list of related tutorials on their website [here](http://www1.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/tutorials-ace.html).

If you are feeling ambitious take a look at [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/).